# not logging in blank screen after login with system error message

Tags: dual-boot, 13.10

when i start my pc it gets to the logon screen, then i put in the correct details. then a blank screen appears, and a message saying system error has occured, cancel or report now so i tried cancel and report now both do nothing i can click it 3 times and then it goes away but my screen still stays blank. this happened out of the blue was working great then next day i try to login and bham problems.

When using the startx command; the only error that appears is "Warning type "one_level" has 1 levels but  has 2 symbols. ignoring Extra symbols. The Xkeyboard compiler reports.

Comment: Does the same happen if you try it with the guest session account?

Comment: When you get to the blank screen, press Ctrl+Alt+F1, if prompted for login, do that. Then try running the command `startx` and add any errors from that command to your question.

Comment: @BrunoPereira yes it does the same on the guest account.

Answer (score 1):

Fixed: just had to uninstall all the nvidia drivers